# Meteor.isCordova is undefined

Tags: meteor

[image]

Meteor documentation says I can use Meteor.isCordova anywhere, like Meteor.isServer and Meteor.isClient. But Meteor.isCordova does not exist - it's undefined. Am I missing something? This screenshot is from Meteor docs 0.9.4. I have multiple projects where Meteor.isCordova is also undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't see meteor.isCordova on the browser it will be on phonegap app only, 
It will be set true when it is cordova bundling, not the regular meteor bundle.

Meteor app has now special bundling for phonegap/cordova app.
and Meteor.startup works as deviceready event for cordova app in meteor,

Also you need to upgrade your app meteor version, in order to have cordova feature enabled.